# Angular ui mask works wierd in mobile

Tags: angularjs, input, mask

Trying the expiration date and it’s not entering correctly
when I enter 12/18, it bumps the 12 from the month to the year instead of going to the year part after I type in 12 and comes out 18/12

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="cardExp" ui-mask="99 / 99" ng-model="expDate" cc-exp maxlength="4" required />
```

Also focus jumps to the center after digits entering.
Trying on GN5 and S6